# Convert div.class to <div class="class"></div> Textmate

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

My apologies for the post. I realize that this is more than likely redundant but for some reason I can't seem to find my answer.

I believe there is a keyboard shortcut in Textmate for converting something along the lines of

`div.test`

to

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

Any ideas? Anyone know where I can get documentation about this shortcut?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Zen Coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) and [Sparkup](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup).

Comment: I believe the shortcut I am looking for is native to Textmate.

Comment: @Bruno — No, @Bradford's answer is the right one. Your example is the textbook example of how to use Zen Coding/Sparkup. You expand it with ctrl+e.

Answer (score 1):

Without the additions mentioned by @Bradford, the alternative option is to use the built-in snippets. For example (when the document is set to be HTML), typing `div<TAB><TAB>test` inserts the following and places the cursor on the second line:

```
<div id="test">

</div>
```